# If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a linear isomorphism between $X$ and $f(X)$, then show that there exists a continuous linear map from $Y^*$ onto $X^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

For any $x \in X$, define the set $\mathcal{F}(X) = \overline{\operatorname{span} \{ \delta_x : x \in X \}}$ where $\delta_x(f)=f(x)$ for all $f \in$ $\operatorname{Lip}_0(X)$.

The set $\operatorname{Lip}_0(X)$ is the set of all real-valued Lipschitz functions which vanish at $0$.

Note that $\delta_x$ is an evaluation functional on $\operatorname{Lip}_0(X)$ and  dual space of $\mathcal{F}(X)$ is $Lip_0(X)$.

In the [proof of theorem $7$](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.07209v3.pdf), which states that $\mathcal{F}([0,1])$ is not linearly isomorphic to $L_1(\mu)$ for every measure $\mu$, the author states the following:

> If there is a measure $\mu$ with $\mathcal{F}([0,1])$ linearly isomorphic to a subspace of $L_1(\mu)$, then there is a continuous linear mapping from $L_{\infty}(\mu)$ onto $Lip_0([0,1])$. Since $L_{\infty}(\mu)$ is a commutative C$^*$-algebra, there exists a compact Hausdorff space $K$ such that $L_{\infty}(\mu)$ is isometric to $C(K)$.

Question: How to prove the above two statements?

For first statement, I think we use adjoint mapping, but I don't know how to apply it here. For the second, it resembles the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: For continuous linear operators between Banach spaces, bounded below is a dual property to surjectivity (see Lemma 1.30 in Pietro Aiena's book on Fredholm and Local spectrial Theory).  In particular, if $J:\mathcal{F}([0,1])\to L_1(\mu)$ is bounded below then $J^*:L_\infty(\mu)\to Lip_0([0,1])$ is a surjection.  I am not sure about the other fact, though.  Supposedly $L_\infty[0,1]$ is isomorphic to a $C(K)$-space, but I was not aware that this was true for arbitrary measures $\mu$.

Comment: @anonymous It is true (as stated in the quote) for arbitrary commutative C*-algebras. This is what is known as the Gelfand-duality

Comment: I have seen that both here and in some other questions you have offered a bounty but received no answer. Maybe you might be interested in my suggestion to collect somewhere unresolved bounties. For details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/23715) and [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/43020/2016/7/26). Feel free to ping me here or [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/19138/martin-sleziaks-room) after you see this comment. (Since it is unrelated to the question, I prefer removing it after it served its purpose.)